# Converse of central angle is double angle subtended at circumference

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

I have an exercise to explain why the following theorem does not have a converse:

> **Theorem**.
>
> The angle subtended at the centre of the circle by a chord is double the angle subtended at the circumference.

But why is the following not the converse?

Suppose $k$ is a circle centered at $O$ with $P,Q\in k$. Then if $\angle POQ=2\angle PRQ$ for some point $R$, then $R\in k$.

Edit: This appears to be true (see attempted proof in comments). So why does the book say there is no converse?

Reference: *Crossing the Bridge* by Gerry Leversha, p.64

Comment: If $R$ lies on the circumference, in other words, $OR=OP=OQ$ then this always holds true

Comment: @Gokuカカロット If $R$ is on the circumference, we just have the original theorem. My question is about the converse - if $\angle POQ=2\angle PRQ$, does this imply $R\in k$?

Comment: In a circle? Yes, you can easily prove that this is the case (using the original theorem as well) by drawing a diagram @a1402

Comment: So suppose for a contradiction $R\not\in k$, and let $P'=PR\cap k, Q'=QR\cap k$. Then $\angle PP'Q=\angle PQ'Q=\angle PRQ$. But I can't see where the contradiction comes from.

Comment: And also, if this is true, why does my book say this theorem has no converse?

Comment: Edit: I think I got it. Let $R'=PQ'\cap P'Q$. Then $\angle PR'Q=\angle PRQ$ so $R=R'$ and hence $P'=Q'=R'=R$.

Comment: But I still have no idea why the exercise in the book is to explain why there is no converse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here $R'$ us the mirror image of $R$ with respect to $PQ$. Even though the relation between angles hold, it does not have to lie on $k$, aka $\odot O$. This proves that there is no converse of the theorem.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!

Comment: If we specify that R is on the same side of PQ as O, then it would work... right?